# Settings.bundle Not Appearing on Application Updates

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I have an app that does not currently use a Setting.bundle to display setting in the iPhone Settings app.

I am releasing an update that does.

On a fresh install, the settings are added to the Setting App as expected, but upon updating from the old install, the bundle is not added.

Is there some sort of trick to get the Settings App to show my Settings.bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a full clean did the trick. I think the bundle gets cached somehow and even on changes, Xcode doesn't recognize it changed sometimes.